# Tomcat/Java Truststore confusion

Tags: tomcat8, truststore

I am rather confused by the purpose of the trustore file in a tomcat server.

I.e use of the `truststoreFile` parameter when setting up a TLS enabled connector.

According to the tomcat docs:

> truststoreFile
>
> The trust store file to use to validate **client** certificates. The
>   default is the value of the javax.net.ssl.trustStore system property.
>   If neither this attribute nor the default system property is set, no
>   trust store will be configured.

To me this is telling me that for an **inbound** connection to my tomcat server, this is where I would store certificates that a **client** would present. (e.g. a users browser)

Would I really put in 3rd party CA certificates here or other 3rd party server certificates, if my tomcat server wants to make an **outbound** connection to a TLS enabled server (e.g. an LDAPS server)

As per my understanding the place to do this is the **cacerts** file.

Is my understanding of the truststore wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, it is quite confusing.

**If you need to make an outbound connection a 3rd party, you need to add the certificates to cacerts.**

There is a very popular "signing, validation, etc." service for government-owned companies here in Spain, @firma, that just changed its wildcard server certificate and we had to add it to cacerts.